# Previous fragment shows blank screen when back button pressed (using multiple fragmentTransactions)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, transactions

I have an activity that shows two fragments at the same time on tablet and one at a time on handset. Because I am making the app for both tablets and android, I have to separate the functionality of the navigation between fragments into a separate function "displaySecondFragmentOnHandset()".

On the smaller handset when a move from the first fragment to the second and the then try to go back to the first, the screen is blank.

MyActivity:

```
    class CentralActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val manager = supportFragmentManager
    var firstFrag : FirstFrag? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        ...

            var ft: FragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();

            firstFrag = FirstFrag.newInstance()
            ft.add(R.id.real_container, firstFrag!!, "firstFrag")

            if (screenLayoutSize >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
                var secondFrag = SecondFrag.newInstance()
                ft.add(R.id.real_container, secondFrag, "secondFrag")
            }
            ft.commit()
    }

    fun displaySecondFragmentOnHandset (){
        var secondFrag = SecondFrag.newInstance()
        var ft: FragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft!!.replace(R.id.real_container, secondFrag).addToBackStack("secondFrag").commit()
    }
```

Then in my FirstFragemnt, if i'm on a smaller handset I do:

```
    class FirstFragemnt : Fragment() {
          private var viewModel: SharedViewModel? = null

          fun goToSecondFragment(){
          if (screenLayoutSize!! < Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {

            viewModel!!.setMsgInCommunicator(collection)
            var centralActivity: CentralActivity = activity as CentralActivity
            centralActivity.displaySecondFragmentOnHandset()
     }
    }
```

The problem is when I press the back button to go to the first fragment, The screen is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put the `fun goToSecondFragment()` inside of `override fun onViewCreated`

Answer (score 0):

in CentralActivity replace

ft!!.replace(R.id.real_container, secondFrag).addToBackStack("secondFrag").commit()

with

ft!!.add(R.id.real_container, secondFrag).addToBackStack("secondFrag").commit()

Comment: Nope it's not working. The Fragment seems to be working (all the logs in there show when I do `displaySecondFragmentOnHandset ()` ) but the view never changes. It stays on FirstFrag